# Windows Powershell run as admin fails to understand it's admin when connecting

Tags: powershell, docker, daemon

Trying to connect to Docker and I'm getting this in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.27/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> ^C
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> start-service docker
start-service : Cannot find any service with service name 'docker'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker:String) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Obviously since I'm running Powershell as admin I should have elevated permissions? In any case I've run through a few Stack Overflow questions on the subject and no answers have fixed the issue yet. Any help from current SO crowd?

Comment: This does not read like a permissions issue since the error states the service might not be running. I dont know docker but does this happen in both x64 and x86 shells?

Comment: Check proper name for docker service, it's quite possible there's no docker service installed, and thus your connection will fail due to no receiving side.